# Python Threading - argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading, raspberry-pi4

When I execute the code below on a Raspberry Pi, it mostly works and prints Light and Motion detection messages when it should, but mixed in the output I keep getting this error:

`argument must be an int, or have a fileno() method`

with no traceback and no amount of try-except clauses seems to catch it.

```
import time
import threading
import grovepi


def notify(msg):
    print(msg)
    buzzer.alert(.25)


class Buzzer:
    """ Buzzer class for trigger buzzer sounds. Accepts a timing pin """
    def __init__(self, pin, **kwargs):
        self.pin = pin
        grovepi.pinMode(self.pin, "OUTPUT")
        super(Buzzer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def alert(self, timing):
        grovepi.digitalWrite(self.pin, 1)
        time.sleep(timing)
        grovepi.digitalWrite(self.pin, 0)
        time.sleep(timing)


class LightSensorThread(threading.Thread):
    """
        Light sensor thread, monitors light sensor.
        Accepts Light Sensor Pin ID and light threshold before alerting
    """
    def __init__(self, pin, threshold=12, **kwargs):
        self.pin = pin
        self.threshold = threshold
        super(LightSensorThread, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def run(self):
        grovepi.pinMode(self.pin, "INPUT")

        while True:
            try:
                sensor_value = grovepi.analogRead(self.pin)
                if sensor_value:
                    resistance = (float)(1023 - sensor_value) * 10 / sensor_value

                    if resistance > self.threshold:
                        notify('Light Detected - {0}!'.format(sensor_value))
                    time.sleep(.5)
            except Exception as err:
                print("Light Error", err)


class PIRSensorThread(threading.Thread):
    """
        PIR Sensor monitoring thread, accepts PIR Sensor pin
    """
    def __init__(self, pin, **kwargs):
        self.pin = pin
        super(PIRSensorThread, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def run(self):
        grovepi.pinMode(self.pin, "INPUT")

        while True:
            try:
                if grovepi.digitalRead(self.pin):
                    notify('Motion Detected')

                time.sleep(.3)
            except Exception as err:
                print("Motion Error", err)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    LIGHT_PIN = 0
    MOTION_PIN = 8
    BUZZ_PIN = 4
    buzzer = Buzzer(BUZZ_PIN)
    LightSensorThread(LIGHT_PIN, 20).start()
    PIRSensorThread(MOTION_PIN).start()
```

SO is making me add more text to the question even though I don't have much more to say, but I have tried surrounding every distinct block of code with additional try-except error-catching blocks without success.

Comment: You are suppressing the exceptions so you don't get the standard error message. If this really is a fatal error, how about letting it though and let your program fail? Otherwise, in those exception handlers `traceback.print_exc()` would give more info.

Comment: My exception messages are never printing, so it's not my `try` clauses that are catching the error. It's not a fatal error, the application continues to run, but the error messages are intermittently mixed in the output.

Answer (score 3):

For folks coming along after with this problem - I also see this message. The common factor for me is the import of old Dexter Industries code, not grovepi, but in my case easygopigo3 code to access distance sensor and mutex protection.

The messages seem to come from the DI code printing the message and eating the Exception.

Apparently especially on grovepi because grovepi methods do not use mutex protection - see https://forum.dexterindustries.com/t/grove-gps-sensor-slow-to-read/7609/10?u=cyclicalobsessive

From https://dexterind.github.io/GrovePi/api/gpio/

```
IMPORTANT

This library and the other ones too are not thread-safe. You cannot call the GrovePi from multiple threads or processes as that will put the GrovePi into a broken state.

In case you need to reset the GrovePi from your Raspberry Pi, check this section.

The functions don't verify if the input parameters are valid and therefore the parameters have to be verified/validated before that. Calling a function with improper parameters can result in an undefined behavior for the GrovePi.
```